# Android studio: Exit multiple cursor/selector mode

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I am not sure what keyboard combination I pressed to ended up in this mode, How to fix and exit from this mode of selection?

[image]

Comment: Already fixed it, Shift + Fn + Del

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably entered `Column Selection Mode` via an accidental click in the editor context menu (at least that happens to me occasionally). To exit the mode again, just right-click in the editor and select `Column Selection Mode` (which will have a check mark in front of it).